# Firebase Android Authentification 9.0.2 refresh token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication 9.0.2 (Facebook, Google, email/password or anonymous) in my Android app, this part works correctly.

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null && !flagAuth) {
                // User is signed in
            } else if (user == null) {
                // User is signed out
            }
        }
    };
```

After this, I'm listening on `database.getReference(".info/connected")` and `database.getReference(".info/authenticated")`, first time I'm connecting these 2 values are **true** for all authenticated providers. When I'm restarted my application, it is always true.

```
final DatabaseReference refAuthenticated = database.getReference(".info/authenticated");
    refAuthenticated.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            boolean connected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                AppLog.d("Authenticated");
                });
            } else {
                AppLog.d("No more Authenticated");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            AppLog.d("Listener was cancelled at .info/authenticated");
        }
    });
```

But after 1 hour (when my token is expired), Firebase SDK has to refresh the token automatically but it failed with this error

```
pc_0 - Authentication failed: expired_token (Auth token is expired)
```

Or this one

```
pc_0 - Authentication failed: invalid_token (Invalid claim 'kid' in auth header.)
```

I have checked my SHA-1 key in my Firebase project and it is correct.

**EDIT:**
The problem seems to be fixed by Firebase team.

Comment: Just to be sure , u have downloaded and replaced the service json and rebuild u'r project after u added the sha1 key ?

Comment: @AndreClassen Yes my service json is up to date.

Comment: Seems i'm running now into the same issue...